# Stopping computation in R; will I lose results up to that point?

Tags: r

I am running some matrix algebra on a large data set.  Each iteration of the outer most loop populates one row of two different vectors that are allocated to 64,797 rows.  I am printing a counter to screen for the outer loop to check progress.  This might not be ideal.  R is still working, according to task manager and using a good bit of memory and processor.  However, the R console is not responding and I can only read at the end that I am at least to row 31,000ish (there is scroll space, but I cannot scroll down to see the last number printed).  I do not know if the program is "hung" (no longer iterating outer loop) and I am wasting my time waiting, or if I should stick it out.  The machine has been running for a few days.  Given the program's structure, I can END the process and restart from the last row populated.  However, if I end the process, will I lose the previously assigned data in my vector I am populating?  That would be bad, as I'd have to start all over. Here is the code below.  The end goal are the vectors called: save.trace and save.trace2.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(coor.cal)){
print(i)
   for (j in 1:nrow(coor.cal)){
      dist<-( (coor.cal[i,1]-coor.cal[j,1])^2 + (coor.cal[i,2]-coor.cal[j,2])^2)^.5        
      #finding distances between observations
      w[j]<-exp(-0.5*((dist/bw)^2))#computing weight matrix for observation i
      if (dist>bw){w[j]<-0}


   }

   for (k in 1:27){
      xv<-xmat[ ,k]
      xtw[k, ]<-xv*w
   }
   xtwx<-xtw%*%xmat
   xtwx.inv<-ginv(xtwx)
   xtwx.inv.xtw<-xtwx.inv%*%xtw


   xrow<-xmat[i, ]
   temp<-xrow%*%xtwx.inv.xtw
   save.trace[i]<-temp[i]
   save.trace2[i]<-sum(temp*temp)
}
```

Comment: what does this have to do with CRAN?

Comment: @mdsummer: Yeah, that was odd/misleading.  I've removed it from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better example.

```
saved <- 0
for(i in 1:100)
{
  saved <- i
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
}
```

Run this code, and press escape sometime in the next 10 seconds (before the loop completes).

Take a look at the value of `saved`.  It should be more than `0`, indicating that your progress has been stored.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the memory to risk an experiment to answer my question.  I just borrowed another machine, tried it, and indeed you CAN end a process and still retain previously stored information.  I had not run into this problem before.  I attempted to delete my question, but could not.  I'll leave this in case it helps someone else.